# Why is the LT1054 circuit providing far more than double voltage?

Tags: voltage-regulator, charge-pump

I created a LT1054 bipolar doubler circuit. I am using Linear Technology's chip.

My supply source is measured at 6.1V. My finished circuit is providing -16.2V and +21.5V.

Besides being far beyond double, there is quite a difference.

I have never worked with charge pumps before, so I am unsure if this is to be expected, or did I do something wrong. I have went over my circuit several times and it looks fine to me.

[image: LT1054 circuit from data sheet]

**UPDATE**

Read the accepted answer for the solution. With tantalums, I now achieve -12v and +13v from the unregulated circuit under 15mA load on each rail using a 6v source. Entirely sufficient for my needs. Below is the final layout I used on perfboard (in case anyone wants to use it!)

[image: circuit layout]

Comment: What load were you using when measuring the output voltage?  You are running the device in an unregulated mode (not using the FB pin, which is okay), so that might have an effect.  What is the ESR of your capacitors?  The datasheet recommends ESR of Cout (Vout to gnd) and Cin (across CAP+ and CAP-) be way less than 1 ohm.

Comment: @tcrosley I had no load on them. I put LEDs on each output, so each output has around 20mA, and it lowered the voltages significantly to -10.8v and 16.8V. I am certain these caps have pretty high ESR, since they are generic bulk buys.

Comment: I would try to fix the caps.  Read the datasheet re their recommendations.  It's always a good idea to read a datasheet from beginning to end -- I know it's a lot of work, but I seen people (including myself) stung *so* many times.

Comment: @tcrosley Will do. From my understanding, 10uF tantalums should work great for CIN. Would you reason the 10uF tantalums would be sufficient to place in parallel with 100uF electrolytics on COUT? Tantalums become exponentially more expensive above 10uF!

Comment: See below.  I essentially made an answer out of my comments, adding more detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you should never measure the output of an unregulated supply without a load.  Try to choose a load that is close as possible to the final load you think the circuit will see.

From the datasheet for the [LT1054](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1054lfh.pdf), it appears the capacitor selection is rather critical.  In particular, under Capacitor Selection on page 8, it has specific recommendations for C\$_{IN}\$ and C\$_{OUT}\$.

Ironically, in the schematic you copied from page 11 of the datasheet, C\$_{IN}\$ and C\$_{OUT}\$ are not labeled; but from the other examples it is clear that C\$_{IN}\$ is the 10 µF capacitor between CAP\$^+\$ and CAP\$^-\$, and C\$_{OUT}\$ is the 100 µF capacitor between V\$_{OUT}\$ and ground.

The datasheet first says that for *unregulated* circuits (like yours) the nominal values of C\$_{IN}\$ and C\$_{OUT}\$ should be equal.  Clearly their example schematic for a Bipolar Supply Doubler is going against their own recommendations.

Then they recommend using tantalum capacitors with low ESR values for both C\$_{IN}\$ and C\$_{OUT}\$

What I would do, is use a 10 µF tantalum cap, [like this one](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/TPSC106M025R0300/478-5816-1-ND/2136404), with an ESR of 0.3 Ω for C\$_{IN}\$ and C\$_{OUT}\$, and then optionally add a 100 µF electrolytic capacitor (which may have 10 times the ESR value of a tantalum) in parallel with the 10 µF tantalum for capacitor C\$_{OUT}\$.

If you have the parts, you might want to use the tantalum caps for the other two 10 µF shown in the circuit, on the left side of the chip, one connected to pin CAP\$^+\$ and the other to CAP\$^-\$.

Comment: This definitely seems to be the issue. With a different source (a fresh 9v battery), my voltage is much more even on each rail but is dropping significantly with the load. So it appears to be doing exactly what should occur with the high ESR capacitors.

Thank you for the great and thorough response. I'll have the new tantalum capacitors early next week and hopefully able to accept the answer to this discussion!

Also thank you for pointing out that their figure goes against their own advice. I had noticed that last night and it had me a bit confused...